# probability of finding specific character from a random string present in multiple files

Tags: awk, sed, grep

Let us consider the following files each contain unknown number of character.

file_1.txt

```
AACCGCCTTACG
```

file_2.txt

```
CAGGCGTTTAGGTCA
```

file_3.txt

```
GGACTGAACCTGTTAA
```

1. I want to get the probability of finding A at 2nd position.

Answer of the above statement is 2/3 since A is found at 2nd position in 2 files out of 3 files.

2. I want to get the probability of finding G at position 2 to 4 i.e. position 2, position 3 and position 4.

Answer of the above statement is 3/9 i.e. 1/3 as G is found 3 times out of 9 characters

3. I want to get the probability of finding A at **2nd last** position.

Answer of the above statement is 1/3 as A is only 1 file at the 2nd last position out of 3.

Plz help me to get the answer.

I am very new to bash script. And I could not figure it out.

Comment: technically, you're getting a count ... not a 'probability'

Answer (score 3):

You can do it using `awk` :

script.awk :

```
{
    cpt_A++
    cpt_B+=3
    cpt_C++
}

$0~/^.A/{A++}

{
    for(i=2;i<=4;i++) B+=substr($0, i, 1)=="G"?1:0
}

$0~/A.$/{C++}

END{
    print "A is found at 2nd position :", A, "/", cpt_A
    print "G is found at position 2, 3, 4 :", B, "/", cpt_B
    print "A is found at 2nd last position :", C, "/", cpt_C
}
```

The first part is incrementing the counter for each reccord you are going through.

1. A at 2nd position : `$0~/^.A/{A++}` if the second char in your reccord is `A` increment variable `A`
2. G at position 2 to 4 : `for(i=2;i<=4;i++) B+=substr($0, i, 1)=="G"?1:0` for `i` from `2` to `4` if substring begining at `i` and of lenght `1` add `1` if `G` otherwise add `0`
3. A at 2nd last position : `$0~/A.$/{C++}` if the second to last char in your reccord is `A` increment variable `C`

`END{}` at the end of the last input. In this case print results.

Comment: `slice = substr($0, 2 , (4-2+1)); B += gsub("G","",slice)` might be simpler. +1

Comment: @Fravadona for a beginner I would think that the method I used is easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Ruby to do that:

```
ruby -e '
s1="AACCGCCTTACG"
s2="CAGGCGTTTAGGTCA"
s3="GGACTGAACCTGTTAA"

# first one:
ss=[s1,s2,s3].map{|s| s[1]}
puts (ss.count("A").to_f / ss.length).to_r.rationalize(0.05)

# second
ss=[s1,s2,s3].map{|s| s[1..3]}.join
puts (ss.count("G").to_f / ss.length).to_r.rationalize(0.05)

# third
ss=[s1,s2,s3].map{|s| s[-2]}
puts (ss.count("A").to_f / ss.length).to_r.rationalize(0.05)'
```

Prints:

```
2/3
1/3
1/3
```

I wrote this is Ruby to show language agnostic concepts of what you are asking.

> I want to get the probability of finding A at 2nd position.

To answer that,

1. Get all chacters at the second position and calculate the length;
2. Find out how many characters are equal to `'A'`;
3. Calculate the fraction of the second (character count) divided by the first (length).

In Ruby, you can get a new array of all the second chacters of an array of strings like so:

Given:
> a
=> ["AACCGCCTTACG", "CAGGCGTTTAGGTCA", "GGACTGAACCTGTTAA"]

New array of all the second characters:

```
> a.map{|string| string[1]}
=> ["A", "A", "G"]
```

Now do the math:

```
> ss=a.map{|s| s[1]}
=> ["A", "A", "G"]

> n=ss.count("A").to_f
=> 2.0

> n/ss.length
=> 0.6666666666666666

> (n/ss.length).to_r
=> (6004799503160661/9007199254740992)  # .6666~ is not exact in binary...

> (n/ss.length).to_r.rationalize(0.05)
=> (2/3)
```

And so on...

In Bash you will need to use `bc` for arbitrary floats or keep the numerator and denominator as integers.

In awk, (first problem) you could do:

```
echo 'AACCGCCTTACG
CAGGCGTTTAGGTCA
GGACTGAACCTGTTAA' | awk '{s=s substr($1,2,1)}
END{printf "%s/%s\n",gsub(/A/,"A",s), length(s)}'
```

Prints:

```
2/3
```

etc.